# How would one create 2D array in width/height style

Tags: python, arrays

I am studying Python and wherever I go I see 2D arrays initialized like a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].

How would one go with creating a width/height 2D styled array in lets say 1:1 ratio?

I am trying to draw a grid using p5py library in this style: https://www.pyseroptics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/R1_Grid-1.jpg.

```py
columns = 50
rows = columns

area = [columns]

#----------------------------#
for i in range(columns):     #
    rows = []                #
    for j in range(columns): # Main part of this question
        rows.append(input()) #
    area.append(rows)        #
#----------------------------#
```

Above you can see what variables I used and how I tried doing it.

Would this be the correct way of doing it? I am not an expert but when it comes to 2D arrays it is like I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close to what you want to achieve. If we run your code through a Python interpreter (like IDLE), change `columns` to 3 for easier testing, and provide nine `4`s as input, we get the following result:

```
[3, ['4', '4', '4'], ['4', '4', '4'], ['4', '4', '4']]
```

The reason that the extraneous `3` appears at the beginning of the array is because of this statement:

```
area = [columns]
```

This initializes `area` as an array with the only element being `columns` (or in other words, `area = [3]`). To fix this, we can simply change the line to initialize `area` as an empty list before using our for loops to grab user input. You already do this somewhere else in your code... See if you can figure it out! :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! Will try now!

Comment: It seems to be working fine, hopefully I won't mess something else up haha! Thanks!